# SQL ORDER by STRING weird syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Is there a less ugly/more programmatic way to solve this:

```
ORDER BY CASE 
 WHEN lessonID = 'lesson_1' Then 1  
 WHEN lessonID = 'lesson_novid_1' Then 2 
 WHEN lessonID = 'lesson_2' Then 3 
 WHEN lessonID = 'lesson_novid_2' Then 4 
 WHEN lessonID = 'lesson_3' Then 5 
 WHEN lessonID = 'lesson_novid_3' Then 6 
 WHEN lessonID = 'lesson_4' Then 7 
 WHEN lessonID = 'lesson_novid_4' Then 8 
 WHEN lessonID = 'lesson_5' Then 9 
 WHEN lessonID = 'lesson_novid_5' Then 10 
 WHEN lessonID = 'lesson_6' Then 11 
 WHEN lessonID = 'lesson_novid_6' Then 12
 WHEN lessonID = 'lesson_7' Then 13 
 WHEN lessonID = 'lesson_novid_7' Then 14
 WHEN lessonID = 'lesson_8' Then 15
 WHEN lessonID = 'lesson_novid_8' Then 16
 WHEN lessonID = 'lesson_9' Then 17
 WHEN lessonID = 'lesson_novid_9' Then 18
 WHEN lessonID = 'lesson_10' Then 19
 WHEN lessonID = 'lesson_novid_10' Then 20
 WHEN lessonID = 'lesson_11' Then 21
 WHEN lessonID = 'lesson_novid_11' Then 22 
 WHEN lessonID = 'lesson_12' Then 23 
 WHEN lessonID = 'lesson_novid_12' Then 24
End ASC
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to find the number and cast it to an integer:

```
ORDER BY
    CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(lessonID, 'lesson_', ''), 'novid_', '') AS INT),
    lessonID
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aea03/1)

Note that this query will not be able to use an index to perform the ordering. You could consider using a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and indexing it to improve the performance.

Answer (score 2):

Create a table with columns for lessonId and sortPosition. Join to that and order by sortPosition.

Answer (score 0):

nope, that's pretty much what you have to do, but i've used a slightly different (cleaner?) syntax:

```
ORDER BY (CASE lessonID
 WHEN 'lesson_1' Then 1   
 WHEN 'lesson_novid_1' Then 2  
 WHEN 'lesson_2' Then 3  
 End) ASC
```

it's pretty much the same thing though.  sadly you can't use variables/parameters to sort on as you've probably found out

```
ORDER BY @parameter DESC
```

Maybe MS will put that in a future release =)

Answer (score 0):

Pile all of the choices into a delimited string and order on the substring position:

```
order by CharIndex( '|' + lessonID + '|', '|lesson_1|lesson_novid_1|...|' )
```

Personally, I prefer WW's answer using a lookup table.